# What is the best solution for storing PDF documents online for users to access through my App?

Tags: database, file, storage

I am creating an App in swift. One of the features I want the App to have is for users to be able to access a bunch of documents (Technical Manuals and Forms). I obviously don't want this stored on device so an internet option is best. However, I don't know what is the best (cheapest) way to go about this. Amazon AWS? Google Drive? my own fileserver at home? Just need someone to point me in the right direction on what is the best solution to have users access documentation. Thanks

Comment: Join [JabRef online](https://github.com/JabRef/JabRefOnline) development or use CiteDrive (closed source). These are the online services you are looking for

Answer (score -1):

Of course there is no way better than storing them Locally ( on your fileserver ) , because this way you can manager the sizing depending on your needs ... however the availability ( if it's at home ) isn't garenteed. 
So the second better choice is a free online solution ( if you don't have a lot of documents ), you can try **Google Drive**, or program an api to store and retrieve your Files on **Github** ( if files < 25Mb, create a private repo and store it there ). I personally think that AWS should be your last solution.

Hope this guide you to the right way

Comment: Thanks Youssef, I would be using several files, some larger than 25Mb. I thought about having my own local file server but I move around a lot because of my job, and not sure the bandwidth would be able to handle all the requests I’d be getting from my users. So Id probably have to do an online solution. I’m just not sure which is the right one. Even on AWS I wouldn’t know what to choose. Should I host a website that acts as a repository? Or are there better solutions to access data through an app?

Comment: In this case, you should check some solutions like FlippingBook, and their api is quiet impressive. For reference : https://apidocs.flippingbook.com/